# How to use a macro to format a table of any size

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a table with, say, 50 rows and 10 columns, and have created a macro easily enough that can format it. However, I can see that 50 and 10 are explicitly stated in the VBA code. What do I need to change for this macro to work on a table of any size?

Here's a snippet from the start of the code:

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$J:$50"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table1"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight8"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You really should avoid using `Select`.  `CurrentRegion` works, but it is good to learn how to find the last row and last column of your data set.  You also want to declare your variables.

```
Sub Test()
    
    Dim LC As Long
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    LC = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LR, LC)), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
    ws.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight8"

     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CurrentRegion.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion , , xlYes).Name = _
"Table1"
```